# Create and use group without restart

Tags: ansible

I have a task, that creates a group.

```
- name: add user to docker group
  user: name=USERNAME groups=docker append=yes
  sudo: true
```

In another playbook I need to run a command that relies on having the new group permission. Unfortunately this does not work because the new group is only loaded after I logout and login again.

I have tried some stuff like:

`su -l USERNAME`

or

`newgrp docker; newgrp`

But nothing worked. Is there any change to force Ansible to reconnect to the host and does a relogin? A reboot would be the last option.

Comment: Unless you explained something wrong, groups are created using `group` module, not `user`.

Comment: He probably meant to say "adds the user to a group". Installing docker would have created the group already. (Incidentally I'm facing this exact same issue)

Comment: Exactly this is my problem. The group does already exist.

Comment: My thought is that this has to do with the way ansible persists in keeping an ssh session connected to your host in order to speed up the running of plays.  What version of ansible are you using, and what, if any settings do you have in your ansible.cfg with respect to ssh?

Comment: Might sound weird, and most likely would not be the most reliable thing in the world, but maybe restart sshd??..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ansible Permissions Issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19867298/ansible-permissions-issue)

Comment: The current answer marked correct by udondan is no longer relevant or correct. See @xiaket's answer regarding the meta task which is the official and supported way of doing this now.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You can use an [(`ansible.builtin.`)`meta: reset_connection`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/meta_module.html) task:

```yaml
- name: Add user to docker group
  ansible.builtin.user:
    name: USERNAME
    groups: docker
    append: true

- name: Reset ssh connection to allow user changes to affect ansible user
  ansible.builtin.meta:
    reset_connection
```

Note that you can *not* use a variable to only run the task when the `ansible.builtin.user` task did a change as “`reset_connection` task does not support `when` conditional”, see [#27565](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/27565).

The `reset_connection` meta task was added in Ansible 2.3, but remained a bit buggy until excluding v2.5.8, see [#27520](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/27520).

While the `reset_connection` task itself does not support `when` conditions, you still can use conditional task inclusion like this:

```yaml
- name: Add user to docker group
  ansible.builtin.user:
    name: USERNAME
    groups: docker
    append: true
  register: add_to_docker_group_result

- name: Include reset connection tasks
  ansible.builtin.include_tasks: reset_connection.yaml
  when: add_to_docker_group_result.changed == true
```

And the `reset_connection.yaml` file to include:

```yaml
- name: Reset ssh connection
  ansible.builtin.meta: reset_connection
```

Comment: Just a side note, although this works great for ssh connections, it won't work for local host/the ansible server. For the local host ansible server you'll need to run  "exec sudo su --login $USER" or "exec newgrp $group" but note that those won't work if ran from ansible/bash script (ansible won't see the new updates, and a bash script will immediately exit/stop after running those commands) /those commands only work for an interactive shell.

Comment: or perhaps wrap it in a block: `[{"name":"Add to docker group","user":{...},"register":"result"},{"block":[{"name":"Reset ssh","meta":"reset_connection"}],"when":"result.changed == true"}]`

Answer (score 18):

For Ansible 2 I created a Galaxy role: https://galaxy.ansible.com/udondan/ssh-reconnect/

Usage:

```
- name: add user to docker group
  user: name=USERNAME groups=docker append=yes
  sudo: true
  notify:
    - Kill all ssh connections
```

If you immediately need the new group you can either call the module yourself:

```
- name: Kill own ssh connections
  ssh-reconnect: all=True
```

Or alternatively fire the handlers when required

```
- meta: flush_handlers
```

---

For Ansible < 1.9 see this answer:

Do you use ssh control sockets? If you have `ControlMaster` activated in your ssh config, this would explain the behavior. Ansible re-connects for every task, so the user should have the correct role assigned on the next task. Though when you use ssh session sharing, Ansible would of course re-use the open ssh connection and therefore result in not logging in again.

You can deactivate the session sharing in your `ansible.cfg`:

```
[ssh_connection]
ssh_args= -S "none"
```

Since session sharing is a good thing to speed up Ansible plays, there is an alternative. Run a task which kills all ssh connections for your current user.

```
- name: add user to docker group
  user: name=USERNAME groups=docker append=yes
  sudo: true
  register: user_task

- name: Kill open ssh sessions
  shell: "ps -ef | grep sshd | grep `whoami` | awk '{print \"kill -9\", $2}' | sh"
  when: user_task | changed
  failed_when: false
```

This will force Ansible to re-login at the next task.

Comment: is there a way to add that ssh connection option in the playbook rather than in a config file?

Comment: also, killing ssh sessions seems to prevent ansible / vagrant from logging back in.

Comment: Not that I know of. Though, according to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33935139/2753241) it is possible in Ansible 2 to define it in the inventory, which suggests it might even be possible to set it by defining a variable with that name.

Comment: Thanks. here is the issue I am having http://serverfault.com/questions/747604/how-can-i-have-ansible-restart-the-ssh-session-after-installing-nvm

Comment: Yes, if I recall correctly, the kill/reconnect as posted above does not work any longer since, I think Ansible 1.9, as they changed ssh connection handling. Fails on that level can not be caught with `failed_when` since then.

Comment: Added a solution for Ansible 2 to my answer.

Comment: doesn't `notify` look up the handler by its `name` ? it says `Kill ALL ssh connections` in the `notify:` statement, but `Kill OWN ssh connections` in the `- name:` attribute; did I get something wrong or is that simply a mistake ?

Comment: the solution for Ansible < 1.9 doesn't seem to work on Ansible 2; the `Kill open ssh sessions` task fails with `Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Shared connection to 172.16.200.128 closed.` (DOH!)

Comment: the Ansible 2 Galaxy role doesn't work here, when the task runs, Ansible asks me for the SSH password - not for the Ansible user, but for the local user which doesn't even exist on the remote host being managed - no matter if called as task or per handler

Answer (score 4):

Another option I've found would be to use `async:` to queue up killing `sshd` in the background, without relying on an open connection. It feels incredibly hacky, but it seems to work reliably in both Ansible 1.9 and 2.0.

```
- name: Kill SSH
  shell: sleep 1; pkill -u {{ ansible_ssh_user }} sshd
  async: 3
  poll: 2
```

Pause for 1 second, then kill `sshd`. Start checking for the job to be finished after 2 seconds, maximum allowed time is 3 seconds. In my limited testing, it seems to solve the problem of refreshing the current user's groups with only a minimal delay.

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove socket folder during the play, it works on my side (I don't know if it's the thinest solution). Oddly, `meta: reset_connection` is not working with Ansible 2.4

```
- name: reset ssh connection
  local_action:
    module: file
    path: "~/.ansible/cp"
    state: absent
```

Comment: I'd be curious if this works with localhost connections, because the accepted answer only works with ssh connections. Looks like a cool hack solution if it works though.

Comment: Confirmed, this works with localhost connections