# Ansible Using Custom ssh config File

Tags: ansible

I have a custom SSH config file that I typically use as  follows

```
ssh -F ~/.ssh/client_1_config amazon-server-01
```

Is it possible to assign Ansible to use this config for certain groups? It already has the keys and ports and users all set up. I have this sort of config for multiple clients, and would like to keep the config separate if possible.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can set ssh arguments globally in the [`ansible.cfg`](http://docs.ansible.com/intro_configuration.html#ssh-args):

```
[ssh_connection]
ssh_args = -F ~/.ssh/client_1_config
```

Via behavioral [inventory parameters](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/inventory_guide/intro_inventory.html#connecting-to-hosts-behavioral-inventory-parameters) you can set it per host or group

```
amazon-server-01 ansible_ssh_common_args=~/.ssh/client_1_config
```

Comment: @SakisVtdk AFAIK No

Comment: @SakisVtdk It is possible to define the ANSIBLE_CONFIG environment variable to point to an Ansible configuration file.

Comment: Having tried this on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, Ansible seemed to choke on use of the '~'. Giving the fully qualified path (which will generally match the form /home/<username>/.ssh/<configFile>) fixed it.

Answer (score 25):

I believe you can achieve what you want like this in your inventory:

```
[group1]
server1

[group2]
server2

[group1:vars]
ansible_ssh_user=vagrant
ansible_ssh_common_args='-F ssh1.cfg'

[group2:vars]
ansible_ssh_user=vagrant
ansible_ssh_common_args='-F ssh2.cfg'
```

You can then be as creative as you want and construct SSH config files such as this:

```
$ cat ssh1.cfg
Host server1
     HostName 192.168.1.1
     User someuser
     Port 22
     IdentityFile /path/to/id_rsa
```

#### References

- [Working with Inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html)
- [OpenSSH Config File Examples](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/create-ssh-config-file-on-linux-unix/)

Comment: It also works like this: `server1 ansible_ssh_private_key_file=~/.ssh/id_rsa ansible_ssh_common_args='-p 2222'` in case  you want to have whole configuration in the inventory file. This may not necessarily be the best practice but definitely works when you need to quickly test access.

Comment: Strange glitch in ansible 2.9.16: I did exactly as the answer says (Putting the key file path to the specified ssh/config) and ansible did not connect to hosts until I specified the `ansible_ssh_private_key_file=~/.ssh/id_rsa ` var in my inventory.yml for group all, as the comment says... It connected successfully. I was not able to accept such behaviour, so I commented out the var I just added and made sure the key is specified in ssh/config and guess what - it connected successfully again... So I do not know why it did not work first time... Maybe it caches somewhere its connection data?

Answer (score 19):

With Ansible 2, you can set a **ProxyCommand** in the **ansible_ssh_common_args** inventory variable. Any arguments specified in this variable are added to the sftp/scp/ssh command line when connecting to the relevant host(s). Consider the following inventory group:

```
[gatewayed]
foo ansible_host=192.0.2.1
bar ansible_host=192.0.2.2
```

You can create **group_vars/gatewayed.yml** with the following contents:

```
ansible_ssh_common_args: '-o ProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p -q user@gateway.example.com"'
```

and do the trick...

You can find further information in: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/faq.html

Answer (score 3):

Another way,

assuming you have associated ssh key identity files in configuration groupings for various servers like I do in the ~/.ssh/config file. If you have a bunch of entries like this one.

```sh
Host wholewideworld
    Hostname 204.8.19.16 
    port 22
    User why_me
    IdentityFile    ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    PubKeyAuthentication yes
    IdentitiesOnly yes
```

they work like

`ssh wholewideworld`

To run ansible adhock commands is run

```sh
eval $(ssh-agent -s)
ssh-add ~/.ssh/*rsa
```

output will be like:

```sh
Enter passphrase for /home/why-me/.ssh/id_rsa:
Identity added: /home/why-me/.ssh/id_rsa (/home/why-me/.ssh/id_rsa)
```

now you should be able to include wholewideworld in your ~/ansible-hosts
after you put in the host alias from the config file, it works to just run

```sh
ansible all -ping
```

output:

```sh
127.0.0.1 | SUCCESS => {
    "changed": false,
    "ping": "pong"
}
wholewideworld | SUCCESS => {
    "changed": false,
    "ping": "pong"
}
```

Comment: did you test this with a custom config that was not using port 22? my ssh command hits the correct ssh port but ansible still only tried port 22 (and am not using paramiko) no matter what is specified in the custom .ssh config file. 
`vagrant ssh-config > ~/.ssh/my_custom.config` puts out the correct port for the vagrant in a 'ssh config' file format but ansible w/ssh-agent is not using it.  Since that port changes I'd like to have ansible honor the custom ssh config file for the ssh port instead of having some hack push it to an ansible inventory file