# Ansible SSH and Playbook

Tags: ansible

The current version Ubuntu I have is 20.10, the version of Ansible 2.9.9.

I have Eve NG with Cisco VIRL Routers on IOS 15.6

First I came across that Ubuntu was unable to SSH to cisco router, due to no matching key exchange method found. Their offer: `diffie-hellman-group1-sha1`, I found a work around using `~/.ssh/config`. File using the following link

**`~/.ssh/config` file:**

```
Host 192.168.100.2
KexAlgorithms=+diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
Host 192.168.100.3
KexAlgorithms=+diffie-hellman-group1-sha1_
```

Now I am trying to deploy my first playbook.

When I try to run the playbook I get the following error:

```
fatal: [CSR-1]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Connection type ssh is not valid for this module"}
fatal: [CSR-2]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Connection type ssh is not valid for this module"}
```

I can SSH from Ubuntu to each router as I used `~/.ssh/config`, but I don’t know how to make sure Ansible to use the `~/.ssh/config` file.

I try in `ansible.cfg` file `ssh_args = -F /home/a/.ssh/config` ß the location of the SSH file, but cannot seem to get it working.

I have spent several hours Google around, but cannot find a fix.

**`ansible.cfg`**

```
[defaults]
inventory =./host
host_key_checking = False
retry_files_enabled = False
gathering = explicit
Interpreter_python = /usr/bin/python3
ssh_args = -F /home/n/etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf
```

**Playbook**:

```
hosts: CSR_Routers
tasks:

name: Show Version
ios_command:
commands: show version
```

**`all.yml`**:

```
ansible_user: "cisco"
ansible_ssh_pass: "cisco"
ansible_connection: "ssh"
ansible_network_os: "iso"
ansbile_connection: "network_cli"
```

Comment: Maybe place it a dedicated section and point to to the actual file: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28553307/ansible-using-custom-ssh-config-file

Comment: As it says, `ssh` is not a valid connection type for Cisco routers (IOS).  Get rid of that setting in `all.yml`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SSH FIX - after posted in Reddit

```
nano /etc/ssh/ssh_config
KexAlgorithms +diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
Ciphers +aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc
systemctl restart ssh


nano /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
[defaults]
host_key_checking=False
timeout = 30
```

Video with details
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?app=desktop&list=PLov64niDpWBId50D_wuraYWuQ-d02PiR1

Answer (score 0):

If you see into the [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/ios_command_module.html) don't use SSH as connection type, but `network_cli`. So - you don't talk to the device via default ssh, but via `network_cli`. Put that as a host specific var into your inventory.

```
all:
  hosts:
    CSR_01:
      ansible_host: 192.168.100.2
      ansible_connection: "network_cli"
      ansible_network_os: "ios"
      ansible_user: "cisco"
      ansible_password: "cisco"
      ansible_become: yes
      ansible_become_method: enable
      ansible_become_password: "cisco"
  children:
    CSR_Routers:
      hosts:
        CSR_01:
```

Based on your playbook, this inventory contains a group "CSR_Routers" and the only device on it is CSR_01 with IP 192.168.100.2. The connection type of that device is not ssh but network_cli.

- remove the ssh_args from your ansible.cfg
- remove ansible_ssh_pass, ansible_connection, ansible_user, ansible_network_os, ansbile_connection from your all.yml. This should be host specific (be aware of other devices in your inventory that are not an IOS device

So you call your playbook with:

```
ansible-playbook -i inventory.yaml playbook.yml
```

Also - have a look at the IOS specific documentation in [Ansible](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/network/user_guide/platform_ios.html)

Comment: I have tried create a inventory file. 
——
all:
  hosts:
    CSR-01:
      ansible_host: 192.168.0.2
      ansbile_connection: "network_cli"
      ansible_ssh_user: cisco
      ansible_ssh_pass: cisco

&Playbook
---
- hosts: CSR-01 
  tasks:
   - name: Backup  
     ios_command:
        commands: show run  

I get the same error

 ansible-playbook -i inventory.yml Test_SSH.yml 


TASK [Backup] 
fatal: [CSR-01]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Connection type ssh is not valid for this module"}

Comment: Remove ALL the ansible_ssh_... vars from that host - they are not necessary. Please read the documentation of the ios_command. And maybe try (before running the command) output all hostvars of CSR-01. There is still some reference to SSH.

Comment: There was a typo in my first inventory.